# Best and fastest way to calculate distances when there is too much data?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing a WCF service in C#. I need to calulate distance of users with respect to current user login. For example, I need all users that are currently within 10 KM of current user.

Data looks something like that.

```
User    Longitude   Latitude
1   71.23232    31.23232
2   69.23232    30.23232
3   68.23232    28.23232
4   67.23232    27.23232
.
.
1000    23.22332    45.22323
```

I am using below method to calculate distance.

```
public static double Distance(double sLatitude, double sLongitude, double dLatitude, double dLongitude, char unit='m')
{
    var sCoord = new GeoCoordinate(sLatitude, sLongitude);
    var dCoord = new GeoCoordinate(dLatitude, dLongitude);

    if(unit == 'm')
        return sCoord.GetDistanceTo(dCoord);
    else if(unit == 'k')
        return (sCoord.GetDistanceTo(dCoord))/1000;
}
```

User 1 is logged in and I need to get all users who are in range of 10 KM or 20 KM of User 1. Is there a fatest way to get such users? I am usig SQL server at backend. Please advise.

Comment: A handy trick when comparing distances is to eliminate the computationally expensive square root by comparing the squared distances.  So to find all users within 10 km of the current user, calculate `(x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2` (distance squared) and compare it to 100km^2.  (Note that these calculations won't work on lat/lon values; you'd need to be working in a projection.)

Comment: @VMAtm it is not duplicate of this question at all.

Comment: @eocron You're going to need more explanation than "not duplicate" to convince people it's not, because it looks awfully similar (getting distances between two lat/long coordinates).

Comment: one of the ways to find clusters of related objects (it's used in computational geometry f.e) is using of [Segmented Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree). Not sure though, if the data in your SQL Server can be stored in that way, or it makes sense to load all data and construct that tree in-memory. Anyway, worth looking at.

Comment: @eocron You can find the solution in the linked question, as there are geo-distance calculations in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use the geography spatial type.  This will allow you to query the database and order by distances.

Check this out:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766(v=sql.100).aspx

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2690/calculate-the-geographical-distance-between-two-cities-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

In a range under 100NM, the following code will indicate you if another user is located under specified distance (with good precision and excellent performance).

```
public static bool IsWithinRadius(double radius,double sLatitude, double sLongitude, 
                                  double dLatitude, double dLongitude, char unit='m')
{ // [sLatitude,sLongitude] defines the "center", i.e. the location of the current user.
    if(unit == 'm') radius=radius/1000 ; 
    double deltalat = (sLatitude -dLatitude )*40000f/360f ;
    double deltalon = (sLongitude-dLongitude)*40000f/360f ;
    if (deltalon>20000f) deltalon=40000f-deltalon ; // Points on both sides of meridian 0
    double loncorrection = Math.Cos(sLatitude*Math.PI/180);
    deltalon = deltalon*loncorrection ; 
    return Math.Sqrt(deltalat*deltalat+deltalon*deltalon)<radius ;   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This task is called 'spatial index construction'. You can use R-tree for this task. It's sole purpose is to index such data for further search. More [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

Framework with implementation can be found in pretty popular [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) project.

Comment: Maybe some arguments, downvoter?

Answer (score -1):

A cool idea, if possible, is keeping updated precomputed distance information of the users to a certain fixed point. This could be a simple dictionary with the rounded down distance in km as a key. Everytime a new user is registered, simply update your precomputed distance cache.

And what for? Well, when you need to evaluate users inside a range `R` form user `X` simply evaluate the distance of `X` to the reference, lets call it `D`, and then discard all users whose precomputed distance to the reference is larger than `D + R` or smaller than `D - R`. When the amount of users is high, this can have a big impact in performance.

This wouldn't be possible if user locations are very dynamic; if you have to freqeuntly update the precomputed distances then the solution is self defeating. But, having no context to go by, here is the idea in case its of any use.